# Leveling floors and Installing windows

Tags: windows, floor

I have a sagging 1930s house and plan to level the floors using I-beams and jacks.  I've read that the process is very slow and I'm also wanting to install windows.  Will it cause any kind of problems to have windows installed before the floor is leveled?  I wasn't sure if it would cause the windows to not open properly, affect their angle, etc.

Comment: Do you know if your house was built using "Balloon Framing"?

Comment: Are you leveling floors or the foundation? Do you expect the exterior walls to move at all? If so, there's your answer.

Comment: I'm unsure about balloon Framing.  We would just be leveling the floors, the foundation seems fine.

Answer (score 1):

Level floors first, windows only after. If the window square-ness, level-ness or plumb-ness are affected by the floor leveling, then you'll have window installations that last. The other way could rack the windows into inoperability or at a minimum release any caulking seals.

Comment: That's what I kinda figured but I wanted to make sure.

Comment: Well, I think you were right. No reason to possibly do work twice.